# jQuery "Class" troubles - "Unexpected token this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I am currently using a script for Classes: http://digg.googlecode.com/files/Class-0.0.2.js

I have the latest version of jQuery loaded.

This is my code.

```
var Deck = Class.create({
    init: function() {
        var this.list = [];
    },
    console: function() {
        console.log(this.list);
    },
    addCards: function (elemone, elemtwo, elemthree) {
        $(elemone).each(function(i, el) {
        var values = $(elemtwo, this).text();
        if ($(elemthree, this).text() == "2") {
            this.list.push(values);
        }
            this.list.push(values);
        });
    }
});
```

I'm getting the error "Unexpected token this" just by loading the above code.

The expected behavior is creating an object with this

```
var deck = new Deck();
```

Then adding a list of cards found by addCards with this

```
deck.addCards(elements, go, here);
```

And finally accessing it with `deck.list` or within the functions by `this.list` (the latter of which I believe causes the error). Changing `var this.list` to just `this.list` causes another error - `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var this.list = [];` is the problem `this.list = [];` will do...

`this.list` is not a variable, here `list` is a property of an object referred by `this` so there is no need to use `var`.

Also there is a context problem in your each loop, so

```
var Deck = Class.create({
    init: function () {
        this.list = [];
    },
    console: function () {
        console.log(this.list);
    },
    addCards: function (elemone, elemtwo, elemthree) {
        var self = this;
        $(elemone).each(function (i, el) {
            //here this referrs to the current element being iterated on, not the Deck object so use a closure variable
            var values = $(elemtwo, this).text();
            if ($(elemthree, this).text() == "2") {
                self.list.push(values);
            }
            self.list.push(values);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `var` in front of `this.list` — you are assigning a property to an already existing object, not creating a new one.

Comment: Changing `var this.list` to just `this.list` causes another error - `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: That's because in your `.each()` function scope, `this` refers to something else. Either use jQuery's `$.proxy()` or do a simple cache of your object `var self = this` and use that reference inside your each